# How to programmatically check if password is valid in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7 and creating a custom form to update user password. Before i have to check if the old password user give really is the user password.

Is there a way to do this in Drupal 7?

Thank's for your help!

Comment: User have this functionnality , why do you need to remake it twice  ?

Comment: my goal was to provide a form inside a form for an account management using profile2 to add custom file. So i had to use markup to create an html div inside the management form where i put the update passwords fields. I'm then using ajax to update the password of the user without submitting the management account form. Don't know if i'm clear, it was a weird request from costumer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using user_check_password does the trick :

```
user_check_password($user_old_password, $user)
```

Return true if the old password matched the password associated with the user object.